# Using Swift with Int to Bol comes up with an error

Tags: xcode, swift, int, boolean, logic

I'm playing around in the playground to learn swift (finally) and haven't been able to figure out my error. The book i'm reading is for an outdated version of swift and has some differences from the current version of swift.

```
var logic = 20
var logic2 = 15
var logic3 = 20

var test1 = (logic=logic2 && logic2==logic3 || logic3==logic*2)
```

The output window says "Bool is not convertible to Int".

How can I change my test variable to make the logic statement not return an error.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that you are trying assigning the data in first expression:

```
logic=logic2
```

but you should compare it (==):

```
logic==logic2
```

Add one more equal sign:

```
var test1 = (logic==logic2 && logic2==logic3 || logic3==logic*2)
```

Comment: Oh wow. What a simple fix. How did I not notice that? Thanks!